# symfony httpkernel instantiation full stack framework

Tags: symfony, containers, symfony-http-client

Can anyone point me to the place where the HttpKernel is instantiated or better asked where it is configured as a service?

what I know:

in symfony full stack front controller: "app_dev.php"

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

then we see that:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
```

then in "Kernel.php"

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
{
    if (false === $this->booted) {
        $this->boot();
    }

    return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
}

/**
 * Gets a HTTP kernel from the container.
 *
 * @return HttpKernel
 */
protected function getHttpKernel()
{
    return $this->container->get('http_kernel');
}
```

there is also a comment that the HttpKernel is loaded from the container. Now I'm interested to find out when, where and how this class is instantiated and set as a service.

Thanks!

Comment: It's set by the [`FrameworkBundle`](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml#L12), and it's instantiated at the first call of `http_kernel` service.

Comment: where in the frameworkbundle cause there is where i'm also looking after and cant find the place...

Comment: find what? the service definition is in the `FrameworkBundle`, the class itself is create by the container

Comment: where is the service definition in the bundle? in what file? I read allmost all frameworkbundle files and can not find where the service http_kernel is defined

Comment: I've already linked to you where `http_kernel` is defined.

Comment: OMG I'm realy sorry didn't saw it's a link thank you very much and thank you a lot for your time and help.